# Phonegap android project is not working

Tags: android, cordova

When I run a simple example in eclipse, I am getting the error:

```
cordova activity cannot be resolved to a type,
The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved,
```

Please help me find the solution.

Comment: Follow this article http://techniques-android.blogspot.in/2012/06/making-phonegap-development-environment.html

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you using? Since 3.0, eclipse is no longer required for Android development.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Command Prompt, Execute command $ cordova. 
See if you have properly installed cordova. 
Else in Eclipse, Go to Project then "Clean" your project once.